# Is Close() same as Using statement

Tags: c#, dispose, using

Is `Close()` same as `Dispose()` or using statement. Is it necessary to call using statement even if Close is called?.

I know before disposing of an object, close should be called, so we close the resource and may it available to `Dispose`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx

says `Close` is same as `Dispose`.

Comment: As a general rule you should be using [Using-statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) with everything that implements iDisposable and the object will be disposed (and closed) in the right manner.

Comment: `using` and `Dispose` is defined through the `IDisposable` interface. `Close` is no part of this definition and therefore is not guaranteed to behave the same way. So, the answer is: no, `Close()` is in general not the same as `Dispose()`

Comment: I cannot think of a single .Net library class that requires you to call `Close` before `Dispose` and really any well implemented class shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Close() same as Using statement?

No it is not.

---

> Should you call `Close()` after a `using`?

No, it will break due to access to the disposed object.

---

> Should I call `Close()` before exiting the `using` block?

It's complicated. If the `IDisposable` interface is implemented correctly: no. Otherwise: possibly.

---

`Close()` has no relation to `IDisposable` interface, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

`using` only applies to `IDisposable` inherited objects, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Thus:
**`Close()` and `Dispose()` may not considered to be related in any way.**

When the `IDisposable` interface is correctly implemented, you may assume all clean-up necessary will be carried out. This implies an internal call to a `Close()` method would be carried out. This means that an explicit call to `Close()` should not be necessary.

The other way round; when a object is of type `IDisposable` and exposes a `Close()` method, a call to `Close()` will not be sufficient to properly dispose/clean-up the object. `Dispose()` must still be called, you can do this directly, or through the `using` statement.

You can also let the garbage-collector handle the `Dispose()` call for you (if its correctly implemented, see: [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)) But this is considered bad-practice, since you need to rely on a proper implementation and have no direct control over the GC timing.

Please note, a reason to implement a `Close()` function, is usually to give a developer a way to reuse the object. After calling `Dispose()` the object is considered to be marked for finalization and may not be used any more.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` pattern is useful because it includes a `try ... finally ...` that will protect against exceptions...

If you do:

```
FileStream fs = null;

try
{
    fs = File.OpenRead("MyFile.txt");
}  
finally
{
    if (fs != null) 
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

then **in this case** it would be nearly equivalent (because the `Stream.Close()` calls the `Dispose(true)`)

BUT it is still "wrong"... You use `using` for `IDisposable` classes unless you have a very very good reason (there are some reasons for not doing it... Sometimes the lifetime of an object is very very difficult to track. In that case it is normally ok to no `Dispose()` it.).

The concept of a pattern is that it should become part of you... If you try to skirt from a pattern, then before or later you'll forget about it... And for what? For writing MORE lines that are MORE error-prone?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. I can write a class that has a `Close` and a `Dispose` method that aren't related.

```
class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public void Close() { DoBar(); }
    public void Dispose() { DoBaz(); }
}
```